# Exceptions making a call with emulator

Tags: android, android-intent

When the user clicks a button a number (could be a domestic or international landline) is taken from a text field and passed to a call intent.
Is it possible to make this call on a emulator ?

I have tried got a 'intent not recognised ' exception

This is the exception:

```
 android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.DIAL dat=tel014096432 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else looking to emulate call functions documentation is here http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#telephony